# How to set up Jenkins job that it would start building automatically only when a new git-version of the project is found?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, build

How to set up Jenkins job that it would start building automatically only when a new git-version of the project is found

Answer (score -1):

I've found the answer: when you configure "Build Triggers" just click on "Poll SCM" option